# I Try to write JAX-RS web service. It gives null pointer exception when trying to get XML output

Tags: xml, web-services, spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs

I try to write JAX-RS web service for permit issue... I want to create xml file... I used Jersey plugin... When i execute it the sysemem gives this error.

[image: This is the error]

But when i change to the **APPLICATION_XML to TEXT_PLAIN** the web service works fine... The **findall()** method works fine and it retreive a output for my JSP page... I called the same one for web service.. But it gives null pointer exception...

This is my controller

```
package lk.slsi.controller;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;
import lk.slsi.domain.Importer;
import lk.slsi.domain.Product;
import lk.slsi.security.domain.AuthenticatedUser;
import lk.slsi.services.permitServices;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

/**
 * Created by ignotus on 2/15/2017.
 */
@Controller
@Scope("session")
@Path("release")
public class PermitlController {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PermitlController.class);

    private static final String PERMIT_MANAGE_REDIRECT = "redirect:/permitManage";

    @Autowired
    private permitServices permitServices;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/viewPermit/slsi/Releasedby/Slsi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String viewUpdateAgentPage(@ModelAttribute("SNumber") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("permit", permitServices.getFromId(id));
        return "viewPermitCustoms";
    }

    //This cord for web Service


 @GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/permit")
public List<CustomsPermit> listAllPermits() {
    return  permitServices.findAll();
}
    //End of web Service
}
```

This is my configuration class

```
package lk.slsi.config;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("TransferPermit/restAPI")
public class restConfig extends Application{

}
```

This is my Model

```
package lk.slsi.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomsPermit")
@XmlRootElement
public class CustomsPermit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "permit_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "EntryNumber")
    private String SNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "Application_ID")
    private String applicationID;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "PermitReleaseDate")
    private String appPostdate;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String dtIssue;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "PostedUserId")
    private String userID;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cusdecNo;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String importerVAT;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSNumber() {
        return SNumber;
    }

    public void setSNumber(String SNumber) {
        this.SNumber = SNumber;
    }

    public String getApplicationID() {
        return applicationID;
    }

    public void setApplicationID(String applicationID) {
        this.applicationID = applicationID;
    }

    public String getAppPostdate() {
        return appPostdate;
    }

    public void setAppPostdate(String appPostdate) {
        this.appPostdate = appPostdate;
    }

    public String getDtIssue() {
        return dtIssue;
    }

    public void setDtIssue(String dtIssue) {
        this.dtIssue = dtIssue;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getCusdecNo() {
        return cusdecNo;
    }

    public void setCusdecNo(String cusdecNo) {
        this.cusdecNo = cusdecNo;
    }

    public String getImporterVAT() {
        return importerVAT;
    }

    public void setImporterVAT(String importerVAT) {
        this.importerVAT = importerVAT;
    }

    public String getImporterDetails() {
        return importerDetails;
    }

    public void setImporterDetails(String importerDetails) {
        this.importerDetails = importerDetails;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNo() {
        return invoiceNo;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo) {
        this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }

    public String getInvoiceValue() {
        return invoiceValue;
    }

    public void setInvoiceValue(String invoiceValue) {
        this.invoiceValue = invoiceValue;
    }

    public String getTotQty() {
        return totQty;
    }

    public void setTotQty(String totQty) {
        this.totQty = totQty;
    }

    public String getUoM() {
        return UoM;
    }

    public void setUoM(String UoM) {
        this.UoM = UoM;
    }

    public String getHsCod() {
        return hsCod;
    }

    public void setHsCod(String hsCod) {
        this.hsCod = hsCod;
    }

    public String getProductDesc() {
        return productDesc;
    }

    public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
        this.productDesc = productDesc;
    }

    public String getBlNo() {
        return blNo;
    }

    public void setBlNo(String blNo) {
        this.blNo = blNo;
    }

    public String getCond1() {
        return cond1;
    }

    public void setCond1(String cond1) {
        this.cond1 = cond1;
    }

    public String getCond2() {
        return cond2;
    }

    public void setCond2(String cond2) {
        this.cond2 = cond2;
    }

    public String getCond3() {
        return cond3;
    }

    public void setCond3(String cond3) {
        this.cond3 = cond3;
    }

    public String getCond4() {
        return cond4;
    }

    public void setCond4(String cond4) {
        this.cond4 = cond4;
    }

    public String getCond5() {
        return cond5;
    }

    public void setCond5(String cond5) {
        this.cond5 = cond5;
    }

    public String getCond6() {
        return cond6;
    }

    public void setCond6(String cond6) {
        this.cond6 = cond6;
    }
}
```

My repository is

```
package lk.slsi.repository;

import lk.slsi.domain.Agent;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;

public interface PermitRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomsPermit, Long> {

    @Override
    CustomsPermit save(CustomsPermit customsPermit);

    @Override
    CustomsPermit findOne(Long id);

    @Override
    List<CustomsPermit> findAll();


    @Query("select a from CustomsPermit a where a.id = :id")
    CustomsPermit getFromId(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query("select a from CustomsPermit a where a.SNumber = :SNumber")
    CustomsPermit getPermitBySNumber(@Param("SNumber") String SNumber);

    @Query("select a from CustomsPermit a where a.importerVAT = :importerVAT")
    List<CustomsPermit> getPermitByImporterVAT(@Param("importerVAT") String importerVAT);
}
```

My service is

```
    package lk.slsi.services;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;
import lk.slsi.repository.PermitRepository;
import lk.slsi.security.domain.AuthenticatedUser;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Service
@Scope("session")
public class permitServices {

    private static final Logger serviceLogger = LogManager.getLogger(permitServices.class);

    @Autowired
    private PermitRepository permitRepository;

    public boolean registerPermit(@Valid CustomsPermit customsPermit) {
        serviceLogger.info("Starting to register new Agent. agent : [{}]", customsPermit);
        try {
            Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            long userId = 0;
            String agency = "";
            String units = "";
            List<String> roles;
            if (principal != null && principal instanceof AuthenticatedUser) {
                AuthenticatedUser auth = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;
                userId = auth.getUserId();
                agency = auth.getAgency();
                roles = auth.getUserRoles();

                String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                String userandTime = "UserID "+Long.toString(userId) + " in " + date;
                customsPermit.setAppPostdate(userandTime);
                customsPermit.setUserID(Long.toString(userId));
                customsPermit.setDtIssue(date);
                permitRepository.save(customsPermit);
                serviceLogger.info("Successfully saved the agent in db");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            serviceLogger.error("Error occurred while registering agent. [{}]", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public CustomsPermit getFromId(Long id) {
        serviceLogger.info("Fetching the agent by nic number : [{}]", id);
        try {
            return permitRepository.getFromId(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            serviceLogger.error("Error while retrieving the permit for id number [{}], [{}]", id, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<CustomsPermit> findAll() {
        serviceLogger.info("Fetching Permit List");
        return permitRepository.findAll();
    }

     public List<CustomsPermit> getPermitByImporterVAT(String importerVAT) {
        serviceLogger.info("Fetching Permit List");
        return permitRepository.getPermitByImporterVAT(importerVAT);
    }


    public CustomsPermit getPermitBySNumber(String SNumber) {
        return permitRepository.getPermitBySNumber(SNumber);
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>lk.slsi</groupId>
    <artifactId>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>slsi-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLhSIonNahtionalSingleWindow.git</connection>
        <url>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>1.0.0</tag>
    </scm>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/public/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I got this error on console when run on the web service

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:393) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at lk.slsi.controller.PermitlController.listAllPermits(PermitlController.java:124) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373) ~[jaxrs-ri-2.13.jar:2.13.]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

What is the error?

Comment: What is written at PermitlController.java:124?

Comment: @Mark it has all permits view jsp and web servise